# How to prevent AWS Glue from merging files when I ETL them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, etl, parquet

I'm trying to use Glue to automate copying new files in an S3 bucket to another S3 bucket and changing the format.

They are created as CSV files, I'm trying to convert them into parquet and move them into another bucket.

Glue tries merging these CSV files, but they each have different column headers. I need Glue to treat each file individually instead of merging them (and getting the column headers wrong).

Is there a way to stop AWS Glue from automatically merging files of the same format?

I tried a simple Glue ETL job without inferring the schema, but it tries to merge the files, and somehow gets the column headers wrong when converting from CSV to parquet. I expected Glue to treat CSV files with different headers differently, but it instead tries to create csv files with 100s of headers (while each file has < 20 headers).

Comment: Whats the input path given to the glue job. If you have pointed to a folder then it think all files in folder are of the same structure.. If you target the path to a specific file, then you should be able to get around this problem.. Or use the awswrangler library to read the files as individual files instead of a dataset.